# At the last keyframe the animation looks laggy or slows in blender. How to Fix?

Tags: animation, blender, 3d-modelling

I am a beginner at the blender. I saw a satisfying animation blender tutorial on youtube. then I tried to recreate it. All looked smooth and perfect except the last few frames.

Total frames= 1 to 120 = 120 frames

I have used keyframes for the **rotation** of the objects with ***Bezier interpolation.*** but at the last few frames, the animation looks like slow-motion.

I am a beginner so kindly explain and give a step by step fix or answer for this

Comment: Hey sorry for ur wasting ur time. I just added 30 more frames to the animation and made it a total of 150. Then I added keyframes for all the objects. So it was laggy or slow only at the last frames (147-150) but I need only the First 120 frames of animation. So now it is kind of fixed.

Comment: however, I am happy to know any other fix for it  without any changes in the number of frames or the actual fix in any setting. 